# laravel how to define() constants

Tags: laravel

I googled "laravel constants". All articles say, create "config/myfile.php".

```
<?php
return [
    ...
];
```

I thought "constant" means define()

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/storage/app/public/image')
```

I really want to use define()。 ChatGPT suggests /bootstrap/app.php

At the end, I add

```
define('HTTP_CATALOG', env('APP_URL'));
define('DIR_STORAGE', base_path() . '/storage/app/public/');

echo HTTP_CATALOG; exit;
```

The "HTTP_CATALOG" is empty. $_ENV['APP_URL'] is empty, too.

```
echo print_r($_ENV, true); exit;
```

Empty.

However, I see this

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

This is original /bootstrap/app.php, and it uses $_ENV ??

So
Is /bootstrap/app.php the right place to define constants?
Why is $_ENV empty ?

Comment: Have you seen the [documentation for Laravel configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/configuration)? Choose your Laravel version on the top right. It introduces you to `.env` files, shows an example call using `env()`. Further below *"Accessing Configuration Values"* teaches the usage.

Comment: It's env(), not define(). What I'm saying is define() function.

Comment: *"I really want to use define()"* is not really a strong argument. You're using Laravel. Use the configuration from the docs I linked instead. If you read it you will see something like this `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false)` - so `APP_DEBUG` is a define that defaults to false and comes from the .env, thanks to the `env` call. It exactly eliminates the problems you are writing about.

Comment: You are not answering the question.

Comment: I am not, because I suspect you are trying to solve an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't get the defines to work even though a completely viable alternative exists from Laravel and there is practically no reason to use something else. As already stated, *"I really want to use define()"* is not a very good reason. By that I mean state an objective reason why using defines would be better in your case.

Comment: I think you are doing XY answer. I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not asking how to use env(). I'm asking how do you use define() in laravel. Maybe because of English. Maybe I should not how to define(), I should say where to put define(). I think I said very clear, I want to use define(). If you think define() should not be used in laravel, ok. That's an suggestion, but I will still use define().

Now my solution:
AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->doDefine();
}


public function doDefine()
{
    if(request()->has('https') && request()->getHttpHost() == 'on'){
        $protocol = 'https';
    }else{
        $protocol = 'http';
    }
    
    define('SITE_ID', env('site_id', 1));
    define('APP_URL', "{$protocol}://" . request()->getHttpHost()); // $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    define('HTTP_ADMIN', APP_URL . '/' . env('ADMIN_FOLDER','admin')); 
    define('HTTP_CATALOG', APP_URL); 
    define('DIR_BASE', str_replace('\\','/',base_path() . '/'));
    define('DIR_PUBLIC_STORAGE', DIR_BASE . 'storage/app/public/');
    define('DIR_IMAGE', DIR_PUBLIC_STORAGE .'image/');
}
```

---

Why I want to use define() instead of config()?

1. define() is shorter
   For example, config('constants.someconstant') takes three words. Inside an if() statement, it's not easy to read.
2. Copying(or "porting") from other system.
   I'm rewriting other system using laravel. That system uses define(). Without define(), **it takes a lot of effort**. Also, the example in AppServiceProvider.php, http or https is an example that value change depends on something else.

   return [
   'someVar1' => 'value' // how to change depends on something?
   ];

Maybe we can use (condition) ? 'http' : 'https' or ??, but only for simple situation.

So far, no one really talk about the answer. My answer is: Put the define() in AppServiceProvider. Here, env() woks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out more information about the variabe `$_ENV` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php). It has nothing to do with laravel. You can also see why it might be empty if you check the notes.

> If your $_ENV array is mysteriously empty, but you still see the variables when calling getenv() or in your phpinfo(), check your http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order ini setting to ensure it includes "E" in the string.

To create constants, the "laravel way" is to create a config file (`config/myfile.php`) and return an array.

```php
<?php
return [
    'constant' => 'test',
];
```

And use it like

```php
config('myfile.constant'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want constants in your application I suggest using classes for this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Constant
{
    public const FOO = 'Bar';
}
```

And when you want to use it somewhere:

```php
use App\Constant;

echo Constant::FOO; // Output: Bar
```

Something like this should work.